# Trying to install vmplayer in arch linux

Tags: arch-linux, vmware

I used this article here:

[VMware | ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/VMware)

to try and install VMPlayer on Arch Linux.  It seems to install correctly, but when I run it, it gives me errors. It sends these messages to the console:

```
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module": /usr/lib/libgtk-3.so.0: undefined symbol: g_action_group_action_added

(vmware-modconfig:6271): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "adwaita",
/usr/share/themes/Adwaita/gtk-2.0/main.rc:728: error: unexpected identifier `direction', expected character `}'

(vmware-modconfig:6271): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "adwaita",
```

It then pops up a box saying

```
"Before you can run VMware, several modules must be complied and loaded into the running kernel".
```

I click on 'Install', and then another box pops up and says:

```
"Build environment error! A required application is missing and Modconfig can not continue. xzCheck the log for more details."
```

Comment: Which one was the last step of that wiki page that you executed? What does the log say?

Comment: Per the answer stated [in the forum](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1655714), did you ensure that your system is up-to-date (and maybe rebooted)? Do you have any GTK-related AUR packages that may be out of date?

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was having the error

> vmware modconfig can not continue xzcheck debian

Checking /var/logs/message I saw that the issue was with libcanberra package not installed.
Solved this issue with: `sudo apt-get install libcanberra*`

Answer (score 0):

I had the `Build environment error! A required application is missing and Modconfig can not continue. xzCheck the log for more details.`-problem once too. For me `sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all` worked. BUT please don't ask me what it did to the system.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this simple command

```
sudo apt-get build-essential
```

It will automatically fix all missing package.
If this command is not run than than it will automatically ask a package is missing and you have to install that package and than run that command

Comment: There is no `apt` command in ArchLinux, so your answer won't work.

Comment: Try this instead: sudo pacman -S base-devel

Comment: This worked for me and made sense. Why does the perfect answer get a -1 yet the top answer suggests installing a whole gtk theme to fix an issue that's unrelated to gtk or themes.

Answer (score -2):

this command is archlinux specific:

```
sudo pacman -S build-essential
```